# Poll Rules integration

Tags: 7, rules, polls

How can I integrate core poll module with rules?

I found the [advpoll](https://drupal.org/project/advpoll) module but it is still in dev version and throws errors everywhere.

I am looking to simply trigger a rule after user votes on a poll.

Are there any alternatives to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: I'm thinking about adding a submit handler through `hook_form_alter()` and then making that a custom rules event. Will post back here the results if they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be fairly easy to do through custom module:

**MYMODULE.module**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'poll_view_voting':
      $form['vote']['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_poll_view_voting_submit';
      break;
  }
}

/**
 * Submit handler for poll_view_voting form.
 */
function MYMODULE_poll_view_voting_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Invoke our custom rule and pass the loaded node object as an argument.
  rules_invoke_event('MYMODULE_poll_vote', node_load($form['#node']->nid));
}
```

**MYMODULE.rules.inc**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_rules_event_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_rules_event_info() {
  return array(
    'MYMODULE_poll_vote' => array(
      'label' => t('User casts a poll vote'),
      'help' => t('Triggers when users are casting votes on polls.'),
      'group' => t('MYMODULE HUMAN NAME'),
      'variables' => array(
        'poll' => array(
          'type' => 'node',
          'label' => t('Poll node'),
          'description' => t('Voted poll node.'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey Aram, interesting self answered question (and topic). Nice that you also created that "Poll Rules Integration"-sandbox (which I think you should rename to just "Poll Rules". While reviewing a bit that sandbox, I noticed a crucial typo in line 2 of the readme.txt: I think you should change "action" to "event" there, no? Also, maybe you should expand it with relevant Rules Conditions related to the actual poll vote (the selected option in the poll). Finally, what's stopping you to get it promoted to a full project?